# I have less than 50 reputation but I recieved achievement that I can comment although I actually can't

Tags: discussion, bug

I can't comment because lack of reputation but it showed the achievement. I've tried to comment but of course I failed.[image]

Comment: That's... Pretty odd. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: @PakLongWu you have 119 Reps wh are you unable to comment?

Comment: ＠LittleByBlue I used to have 38 reps only

Comment: @Oli if this fits [tag:bug], should it also not fit [tag:status-bydesign]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually [fairly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133707/why-was-i-notified-of-privileges-that-i-dont-have?lq=1) [common](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67001/reputation-bug-with-privileges?lq=1).

[From an ex-SE employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70472/152101):

```
Take this example:

Bob has 60 rep
Bill accepts Bobs answer, Bob has 75 rep
We trigger a message telling you now you have the bounty priv.
Bill unaccepts your answer
Message is stuck in the inbox.
Obviously, the right thing to do is to pull the message out of the inbox, but that will require a fair bit of redesign to keep the process efficient.
```

Comment: So when the accept/upvote happens, it adds a + record to the reputation log, but when it is revoked, instead of adding a - record saying it was revoked, it just removes the + record, so the information about why this happened is lost?

Comment: @psusi if the events happened too close together, but far enough apart to trigger the notice, it seems so.